# SCSS percentage calculations wrong

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, percentage

I have a grid system in SCSS which calculates the width of the columns based on a 12-column grid. The calculations used to be right but it's recently been compiling wrong.

I get the same output for either of these versions.

**SCSS:**

```
@for $i from 1 through 11 {
  .c#{$i} {
    width: (100% / 12) * $i;
  }
}
```

---

```
@for $i from 1 through 11 {
  .c#{$i} {
    width: 8.3333333333% * $i;
  }
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.c1 {
  width: 8.3333333333%; }

.c2 {
  width: 16.6666666666%; }

.c3 {
  width: 24.9999999999%; }

.c4 {
  width: 33.3333333332%; }

.c5 {
  width: 41.6666666665%; }

.c6 {
  width: 49.9999999998%; }

.c7 {
  width: 58.3333333331%; }

.c8 {
  width: 66.6666666664%; }

.c9 {
  width: 74.9999999997%; }

.c10 {
  width: 83.333333333%; }

.c11 {
  width: 91.6666666663%; }
```

**Used to be:**

```
.c1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

.c2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

.c3 {
  width: 25%; }

.c4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

.c5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

.c6 {
  width: 50%; }

.c7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

.c8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

.c9 {
  width: 75%; }

.c10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

.c11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }
```

Ideally, 6 columns would equate to 50% and the rest accordingly. Any ideas on how can I get it back to what it used to be?

Comment: File a bug report?

Comment: Looks like they increased calculation accuracy.

Comment: What OS are you using? In Xubuntu 16.04 the output is exactly as the second.

Comment: Using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Why do you have 2 versions of the looping code? Won't the first one do just fine? Trying removing the second for loop.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say that I've tried both versions and got the same output. Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, for example:

```
scss --precision 5 main.scss main.css
```

Set precision as the number of digits that you need.

Comment: thanks! I put this in my gruntfile like this and it works!
 
    options: {
      precision: 5
    }